# Left join three tables down and to the left in postgres

Tags: postgresql, left-join, union-all

Suppose I have tables `a`, `b`, and `c`

I want to left join them in such way that I end up with

| table_a_cols | table_b_cols | table_c_cols |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | null |
| a1 | b2 | null |
| a2 | b3 | null |
| a2 | b4 | null |
| a1 | null | c1 |
| a1 | null | c2 |
| a2 | null | c3 |
| a2 | null | c4 |

I know I can achieve this with a combination of `union all` and `left join`, for example (pseudocode)

```
select table_a_cols, table_b_cols, null as table_c_cols from a left join b
union all
select table_a_cols, null as table_b_cols, table_c_cols from a left join c
```

But I was wondering if there is a more succint way to do it in postgresql (I need to do it for several tables).

Comment: You could, theoretically, UNION `b` and `c` together and then join once, BUT if there is indexing on the join key across these tables, that may disrupt the use of it and cause a slower query (maybe).

Comment: @JNevill There is indexing, and it is a key player. This tables are heavily normalized.

Answer (score 0):

The following demonstrates an alternative to using `UNION ALL` to produce the result set described in the original post:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  tag text);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id integer REFERENCES table_a(id),
  tag text);

CREATE TABLE table_c (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id integer REFERENCES table_a(id),
  tag text);

INSERT INTO table_a (id, tag)
VALUES (1, 'a1'), (2, 'a2');

INSERT INTO table_b (id, a_id, tag)
VALUES (1, 1, 'b1'), (2, 1, 'b2'), (3, 2, 'b3'), (4, 2, 'b4');

INSERT INTO table_c (id, a_id, tag)
VALUES (1, 1, 'c1'), (2, 1, 'c2'), (3, 2, 'c3'), (4, 2, 'c4');

SELECT a.tag AS table_a_cols, b.tag AS table_b_cols, c.tag AS table_c_cols
  FROM (VALUES ('b'), ('c')) s(selector)
  CROSS JOIN table_a a
  LEFT JOIN table_b b ON (s.selector = 'b' AND a.id = b.a_id)
  LEFT JOIN table_c c ON (s.selector = 'c' AND a.id = c.a_id)
ORDER BY b.tag, c.tag, a.tag;
```

This approach is more succinct than using `UNION ALL` and can easily be expanded to include additional tables.